# Why don't we use async in Flask?

Tags: flask, asynchronous, async-await

I saw some APIs in Node.js + Express and in Python + FastAPI, both use async functions in their constructs, but I noticed some Github repositories and saw that they don't use async in Flask. I would like to know why this is? Surely errors should occur when we don't use async in functions that need to wait for database data or external apis to return. Could someone explain why not using async in Flask works?

Comment: FYI, Flask only added [support for async/await in Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/) starting from Flask 2.0.0. Maybe the authors and maintainers of those Github repos haven't migrated yet. Or they don't want to. Or haven't had the time to. Only they can answer your "why". It also depends on the app whether or not it needs to do asynchronous calls to DBs or APIs. A local personal app that receives small traffic doesn't need to be async, for example. It is a good practice, but it will not "surely error". I suggest reading related posts on when/why to use async.